# What is the opposite of a pickpocket?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

Without your awareness, a pickpocket will pull some object from your pocket or your bag.
What can we call somebody who does the opposite action, putting something into your bag or your pocket?

*Edit after comments*

1. I asked this question to know if, in English literature or usual expressions, there was an expression which corresponded to this completely unusual behavior; it is the stage that corresponds in a scenario current from limning.
2. *Putpocket* put in a text where it is a matter of pickpocket, seems clear, and for no English-language

Comment: A pickpocket usually takes something you want. But this "opposite" person, does he put something in your bag that you might like, like money? Or something you don't want, like some drugs, when you're about to go through the gates at the airport? Or something questionable, like a sandwich? "Opposite" is a loaded word. The only sure opposite of a pickpocket is someone who respects your property and doesn't go near your pocket. If someone puts incriminating evidence in your pocket, that is called "planting".

Comment: @Kaz I understand "planting" ; but when I wrote 'opposite' I thank at somebody pushing money unobtrusively in a pocket of somebody it will never see again

Comment: I don't really understand you very well. Maybe try http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kaz I asked this question to know if, in  English literature or usual expressions, there were an expression which corresponded to this completely unusual behavior; 
 it is the stage that corresponds in a scenario current from limning

Comment: @cl-r: When someone explains why your question is vague (the way Kaz did), you should **edit your question**, not just elaborate in a comment. Otherwise, everyone needs to read this entire conversation to figure out what you're asking about.

Comment: Once I discovered a cashier had neglected to charge me for an item. Rather than raise a fuss, I sneaked (snuck? I really need to post that question) back into the store and went through the cashier's line again with it. I told my friends I was "shopdropping."

Comment: I think 'put-pocket' makes sense but only in this long discussion. If you introduce it in a story or article without explanation, it will sound very weird and new and will be a stumbling point for many.

Comment: @Mitch - I agree, this expression must be introduced by the environment of the text, and in an ear, she rings exactly for the use that i want thereof to make

Comment: Your text rings very much like a Google translation from some other language, and inventing words won't help.

Comment: @Kaz Searching *putpocket* in Yahoo gave interesting link. Pickpocket  is usual in French, even in subway announces to prevent from them. And for non literature usage I keep it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **[Reverse pick-pocketing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=reverse%20pick-pocketing)** is in fact the art of placing one's own objects into the possession of another, either for entertainment or a charitable matter. However, the correct, street credible term, is *putpocketing*
> [Urban Dictionary]

So it's reverse pickpocketing. It's something you don't see every day.

Some other references for *putpocket*...

From *[Time](https://business.time.com/2009/09/15/recession-era-word-of-the-day-whats-a-putpocket/)*:

> We all know what a pickpocket is. A putpocket, on the other hand, is a pickpocket who has changed his ways. When a putpocket has his hand in your pants, it’s actually a good thing.
>
> Putpockets are former pickpockets who feel bad about their thieving ways, and who go around putting cash into the backpacks and pockets of unsuspecting people on the street.

It's also [in Wiktionary.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putpocket) ("An individual who places money or other items, as a form of kindness or generosity, into another individual's pocket or bag without the other individual's knowledge.")

Comment: Thanks for the link. *Put* seems the good word. I have never see this, but in literature or cinema, it is an interesting point of vue.

Comment: While this seems to be the correct answer to this, very unusual question, to avoid misleading those who come to this page in the future, it needs to be said that neither of these terms is likely to be readily understood. If one wishes to use either of them, one needs to explicitly introduce it, as was done in the *Time* article.

Comment: @jsw29. Agreed, but I'm not even sure that this is opposite behaviour - in both cases you're breaching the security of the pocket, like picking a lock, in which case the word you want is "pickpocket". The idea that there's a different word for placing something in a pocket raises the question of what word would apply if you went into someone's pocket but didn't add or remove anything. I'm seeing "pick" as a security breach and not a specific act of removal.